# Is there a "secure" way, to let users create accounts without password?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, security

I'm building a RESTFul API with Angular frontend. 
I was wondering, if there is a way, to let users register without the need to enter a password - the reason would be to improve Conversion Rates.

Right now my flow is like following:

1. User creates an account with Email + Password
2. The API returns success
3. The user will be automatically logged in with existing Email + PW combination
4. The client retrieves an access_token and stores it in a cookie and adds it to every request

If i remove the password i fear a security leak - since with the registration of the user i would need to directly send the access_token.

Comment: Use Facebook or Google for authentication?

Comment: I already have that :) But i wanted to shorten the funnel for "Email" signup

Comment: What happens if the user moves to other device or delete browser cache?

Comment: Then he has to login again ;)

Comment: You can create an account replacing password with a cryptographic key stored in a secure way in the browser with WebCryptographiApi. Are you looking for this type of solution?

Comment: This would be nice since i wouldn't have to change the API :)

Comment: The api would change a little. 1) The user register in your service  (in the way you prefer) and generates a cryptographic key pair 2) The private key is stored on browser and the public key is sent to server, linked to user account 3) When an authentication is required, the user digitally signs a challenge. The server validates with public key.  Proof of identity is the private key that is stored securely in the browser by WebCryptographyApi